# How to correlate Docker image list with tag list both as returned by API?

Tags: image, repository, docker

One can do
`curl https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/images`
which yields
`{ {"checksum": "", "id": "76ca2fd907879906ba5c936738ccce0b577590040ac8d288f07afb3d34ae8b03"}, ... }`

One can also do
`curl https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/tags`
which yields
`{ {"layer": "5ba9dab4", "name": "latest"}, {"layer": "3db9c44f", "name": "10.04"}, ... }`

How can you now correlate the image IDs with the tag names? Can you rely on the order of the items? Can you get the image id from the shorthand layer id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `layer` is the first 8 characters of the image id.

Comment: Thanks you are right it seems! However, the "images" API cmd returns 504 images for the ubuntu repos, while the "tags" API cmd returns only 19 tags / images. So I suppose the rest are untagged images. They are thus still loadable but not by tag and one cannot know what they are?